# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes on pressing power off or restart

Tags: shutdown, freeze

I am not able to shut down or restart by clicking power off or restart button. I need to manually press the power key on my laptop to force shut down every time.

The desktop screen simply freezes and mouse disappears, and if I leave it for some time then a black screen appears with this:

watchdog: BUG. CPU stuck for 22 sec. Tlp 5770.

And this doesn't go away.

I have tried  everything I could find like

acpi = force , etc.
Installing Nvidia drivers. 
Changing CPU governor to performance from powersaver.

I am new to Linux and really don't know what to do.
I have Lenovo legion y520 with 16 gb, 1 TB, Nvidia GeForce 1050 Ti as the configurations. I removed Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu 18.04.

Please help!

Comment: you can use as a temporarly solution the command line `shutdown -f 0` in your terminal (the computer will shutdown itself when you will press **Enter**)

Comment: Thank you for replying! No, that didn't work. When I pressed enter, the same thing happened! The desktop screen stayed on and mouse disappeared and system hanged. I had to force shutdown again. :(

Comment: so that's not a problem of the desktop

Comment: is it a fresh install of Ubuntu? Do you have edited some config/system files?

Comment: Yes, I installed it a few days ago. No, except from 'acpi' thingy, I haven't touched any other system files. It has been like this from the start. I even tried lightdm today instead of gdm3 but that too hanged my computer when I tried to shut down, so I switched back.  Another thing, I am able to turn on or off the keyboard lights, that's there. But the screen hangs as well as the power indicator light stays on.